# Node Backend Vue (Vite) Frontend, Axios request CORS Error

Tags: node.js, vue.js, cors, vite

I know this issue had been discussed a lot on Stackoverflow but unfortunately I just couldn't find a way to make it work. Long story short, I am building an API using Node JS to that makes a request to MailChimp, and I am calling this API on the client side Vue JS app with Vite. The API works fine with Postman, but it returns `Access to XMLHttpRequest at  from origin has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource` error.

Here is the index js file on the server:

```
const cors = require('cors')
app.use(cors({ origin: '*' }))
app.use('/v1/crm/leads', require('./src/routes/LeadRoutes'))
```

Here is my controller method

```
await addSubscriberToAudience('xxx', req.body.email).then(async (mailchimpID) => {
  if (mailchimpID) {
    let data = {
      references: {
        mailchimpID: mailchimpID
      }
    }
    let updatedLead = await Lead.findByIdAndUpdate(lead.id, data, { new: true })
    res.status(200).json({ data: updatedLead, message: 'New Lead Created Successfully' })
  } else {
    console.log('Null Mailchimp ID')
  }
})
```

Here is how I call it from the frontend:

```
axios.post(APIURL + '/v1/crm/leads/create', data, {
        headers: { 'X-ORIGIN': 'https://example.com' }
      }).then((response) => {
        console.log(response)
      }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error.message)
      })
```

I can see Access Allow Origin is set in the response header in the preflight response:
[image]

Backend is hosted on AWS Elastic Beanstalk and frontend is hosted on AWS S3 Bucket
Any help is needed please, and thank you!

**Edit 1:**
I am making other POST API calls from the website to my backend server, they all work fine. Only this one is not working, and the difference is that, after I make the call from client side to the server, server calls Mailchimp API, and then waiting on response from Mailchimp API before return a success response to my frontend, hope this context helps

Comment: Are you sure it's that specific request that is failing? Because the result of your OPTIONS request clearly contains the ACAO header ...

Comment: Yes I am sure, I tested other requests

Comment: What if you remove the headers from the axios request? Besides that, also try removing the option object from your CORS middleware.

Answer (score 0):

Wich browser are you using?
Apparently on Chrome the wildcard * does't match the localhost url.
There is a ppost here on stackoverflow about this:

[Why does my http://localhost CORS origin not work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10883211/why-does-my-http-localhost-cors-origin-not-work)

And here is the documentation about chrome:

[Chromium Doc](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=67743)

Comment: I am using google chrrome, but even when I deployed the vue app to the server and makes the request, it is still the same error.

Comment: and it's the same error even when I tried in Safari with localhost

Comment: try this ```axios.post(APIURL + '/v1/crm/leads/create', {}, {
        headers: { 'X-ORIGIN': 'https://example.com' }
      }).then((response) => {
        console.log(response)
      }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error.message)
      })```

Answer (score 0):

If you are perfectly sure this CORS errors only occurs on a single POST endpoint (other POSTs work); then this is usually caused by a simple error in the endpoint Controller.

What I think happens is `app.use(responseMiddleware)` adds the `responseMiddleware` actually to the **successful** responses, but not for **failure** responses (eg. `500` s).

I believe Chrome is lying, and CORS header was actually found in the `OPTION` response, but not in the actual `POST` response.